# chrome.local.storage get set - save checkbox checked state and functionality when popup is closed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This is the last step in building my extension and I am seriously stuck. I have researched chrome.local.storage, but can't get it to work.

chrome.storage.local needed to save the checkbox.checked value and if the popup is closed and is reopened the checkbox.checked can be unchecked and the CSS removed.

Updated to use HTML checked in place of aria-checked as recommended by wOxxOm

chrome.storage.local

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        chrome.storage.local.get(['enabled'], function (result) {
            if (result.enabled != null) {
                a.checked = result.enabled;
            }
        });
    
        chrome.storage.local.set({
            enabled: a.checked
        }, function () {
        //is this where I place the checkbox function. I can't get this to work at all
`enter code here`//a.addEventListener("click", async () => {...
    
        });
    });
```

popup.js

```
let a = document.getElementById("headings"); 

a.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    });

    if (a.checked) {

        try {
            await chrome.scripting.insertCSS({
                target: {
                    tabId: tab.id,
                },
                files: ["css/headings.css"],
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(`failed to insert headings CSS: ${err}`);
        }

    } else {

        try {
            await chrome.scripting.removeCSS({
                target: {
                    tabId: tab.id,
                },
                files: ["css/headings.css"],
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(`failed to remove headings CSS: ${err}`);
        }
    }
});
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/popup.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="dimensions" id="dimensions">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Options</legend>
            <ul>
                <li><label for="headings" class="switch--label">
                        <span class="label">Headings</span>
                    </label>
                    <input id="headings" type="checkbox" name="chkAll">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using `aria-checked` attribute? Use `a.checked` both to get and set the state. Also, make sure to use devtools to debug the code: the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools which you can open by right-clicking inside the popup and selecting "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: I don’t know why, learning curve I guess. I’ll keep trying and learning until I get the storage part to work.

Comment: I have updated the code to use a working example. Any help is appreciated as I am completely at a loss.

Comment: The block that starts with chrome.storage.local.set should be moved inside the `click` listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated code as recommended by wOxxOm which works for any others searching a solution to Chrome storage.

chrome.storage.local - get

```
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    chrome.storage.local.get(['enabled'], function (result) {
        if (result.enabled != null) {
            a.checked = result.enabled;
        }
    });
});
```

popup.js

```
    a.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    });

    chrome.storage.local.set({
        enabled: a.checked
    }, function () {
        if (a.checked) {

            try {
                chrome.scripting.insertCSS({
                    target: {
                        tabId: tab.id,
                    },
                    files: ["css/headings.css"],
                });
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(`failed to insert headings CSS: ${err}`);
            }

        } else {

            try {
                chrome.scripting.removeCSS({
                    target: {
                        tabId: tab.id,
                    },
                    files: ["css/headings.css"],
                });
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(`failed to remove headings CSS: ${err}`);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/popup.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="dimensions" id="dimensions">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Options</legend>
            <ul>
                <li><label for="headings" class="switch--label">
                        <span class="label">Headings</span>
                    </label>
                    <input id="headings" type="checkbox" name="chkAll">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
chrome.storage.local.set({key: value}, function() {
   console.log('Value is set to ' + value);
});

chrome.storage.local.get(['key'], function(result) {
  console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
});
```

as you see in the code when you use a string key you don't use "" and if use a variable you put it in [] like this ['key']
I hope this is the problem

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    chrome.storage.local.get(['enabled'], function (result) {
        if (result.enabled != null) {
            a.checked = result.enabled;
        }
    });

    chrome.storage.local.set({
        enabled: a.getAttribute('aria-checked') === 'true'
    }, function () {


    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this in [chrome storage documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/).
You must declare the "storage" permission in the extension manifest to use the storage API. For example:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: I have the storage permission set in the manifest already Omar.

Comment: the chrome storage just didn't work in this case or in all cases. I want to know if the problem is in the storage or in js code

Comment: Definitely in the js code. I have not been able to get it to work at all.

Comment: If you mean the add/ remove js code that works perfectly. The code I have for storage is broken